# Spring boot autoconfiguration not working properly with spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a tiny spring boot application (it is just a proof of concept) running against an H2 in-memory DB and using spring-data-jpa to handle persistence. It consists of a REST API that allows handling posts and comments, so you can create and retrieve posts and comments on those posts.
The application has two JPA entities `Post` and `Comment`, and the problem that I'm facing is that after adding `Comment` entity, the application fails to start, but before adding `Comment` when I just had the `Post` entity the application started and tests passed. It seems that spring boot is not being able to properly autoconfigure JPA.

This is the error I get:

> [ERROR] shouldReturnNullForNotExistingPost(com.devskiller.tasks.blog.service.PostServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.devskiller.tasks.blog.model.Post, at table: comment, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(post)]
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.devskiller.tasks.blog.model.Post, at table: comment, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(post)]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.devskiller.tasks.blog.model.Post, at table: comment, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(post)]

`Post` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @Column(length = 4096)
    private String content;

    private LocalDateTime creationDate;    

    // Getters and setters
```

`Comment` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String author;

    private String content;

    private Post post;

    // Getters and setters
```

**Solution:**
After adding `@OneToOne` annotation to `Comment.post` field the error disappears. But why? I thought that according to JPA spec, it's not necessary to add this annotation in order to create the unidirectional relationship between the two entities with default configuration. Isn't it?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no problem with generating the ID, can you share your full error stack

Comment: @PatelRomil you are actually right, after digging a little bit it seems that error has to be with spring boot autoconfiguration and jpa. I'm going to update the question to provide further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "book_generator")
@TableGenerator(name="book_generator", table="id_generator", schema="bookstore")
```

Try changing your generation strategy to any of the above types. It looks you haven't specified any ways for the framework to identify the generation strategy.

Refer to the below link for detailed explanation 
https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Comment: What do you mean with changing the generation strategy? Just pick one of the above or pick something different to `GenerationType.AUTO`? Because if you don't specify anything, AUTO is the default strategy.